# How to create PayPal button with dynamic receiver?

Tags: paypal

I am developing a web application where users should be able to send other users money via PayPal.

For that reason, I would like to integrate a PayPal button on each user's profile page.

I have already done some research. I have found out that there is a Button Manager which can be used to create buttons.

However, it seems to me that buttons created by the Button Manager are then linked to my PayPal account.

I would like to give the users of my web application the possibility to add their PayPal Account ID which would than be used to create a dynamic button with that user as money receiver.

Is this possible? How would that work?

Note: I know there are Stackoverflow posts which deal with that question however most of them are some years old and seem outdated to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `business` value, the money receiver, for a PayPal button not hosted at PayPal:

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="__________">
```

But you need to generate this code in a secure way. Check out info about non-hosted buttons.